# How to query health kit for total activity minutes by day?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am familiar with `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` in HealthKit, but I am not clear how to run a query for the total number of minutes of activity in a specified time frame, rather than the total number of some `QuantityType` units. Is this covered somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: How are you defining "minutes of activity"?

Comment: @Allan I want to match the 'exercise minutes' that the Health app displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform an `HKStatisticsQuery` specifying the `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierAppleExerciseTime` quantity type to get the total number of exercise minutes for a given time period.